# Setting value of variable from multiple jQuery .val() with multiple selectors

Tags: jquery

I have an application that consists of a bunch of survey questions. I am trying to save the index number of said `<input>` and `<select>` boxes to show them in a specific order.

With that being said, does the statement below look okay?

```
yesNoQuestions[index].question_text = $(item).find("input, select").val();
```

Or will I need to do this (please bear with me as I am a noob with it comes to jquery):

```
yesNoQuestions[index].question_text = $(item).find("input").val();
yesNoQuestions[index].question_text = $(item).find("select").val();
```

Here is the entire function which should save the value to the database via a button.

```
$("#save-button").button().click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var surveyYesNoQuestions = $("#questionList").data("surveyYesNoQuestions");
            var yesNoQuestions = surveyYesNoQuestions.yesNoQuestions;
            $("#questionList li").each(function (i, item) {
                var index = $(item).data("index");
                //Don't need to do all this, just send back the new list since they are being all inserted anyways into a new version
                if (index != null && index != undefined) {
                    yesNoQuestions[index].question_text = $(item).find("input, select").val();
                    //yesNoQuestions[index].question_text = $(item).find("select").val();
                    yesNoQuestions[index].order = i;
                } else {
                    var question =
                        {
                            question_text: $(item).find("input, select").val(),

                            order: i,
                            survey_version_question_id: -1
                        }
                    yesNoQuestions.push(question);
                }
            });
            var params = { surveyYesNoQuestions: surveyYesNoQuestions }
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify(params),
                url: "WebServices/WebService.asmx/SaveSurveyYesNoQuestions",
                success: function (data) {
                    location.reload();
                },
            });
        });
```

Here is the html is before it's submitted to the database;

```
<ul id="questionList" class="ui-sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-widget yesNoQuestion">

<button class="question-delete ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button">

<span class="ui-button-text">delete</span></button><input class="question-input ui-widget-content">
   </li>
<li class="ui-state-highlight ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="width: 700px; height: 30px;">
<button class="question-delete ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button">
<span class="ui-button-text">delete</span></button>
<select id="questionsDropDownBox">

                <option>Yes, 100% </option>
                <option>No, but greater than 75% </option>
                <option>No, but greater than 50%</option>
                <option>No, but greater than 25%</option>
                <option>No, but less than 25%</option>
                <option>None</option>
            </select>
 </li>
```

Here is it after we call for it

```
<div class="yesno-question-row" data-answerid="1020190">
 <span class="yesno-question">1. Some question text....</span>
 <span class="yesno-answer"><span class="yesno-radio required">
 <input class="yesno-radio-button" type="radio" name="yesno1020190" value="Yes" undefined="">Yes 
 <input class="yesno-radio-button" type="radio" name="yesno1020190" value="No" undefined="">No</span>
 <span class="yesno-comment"> <textarea class="yesno-textarea ui-widget-content"></textarea></span></span>
</div>
```

Lastly this creates the rows

```
function createYesNoQuestionRow(questionText, answerText, commentText, answerId) {
            //returns a jquery object of the html for the row
            var $yesNoQuestionRow = $("<div class='yesno-question-row' data-answerid='" + answerId + "'/>");
            var question = "<span class='yesno-question'>" + questionText + "</span>";
            var radioId = "yesno" + answerId;
            var radioChecked = new Object();
            radioChecked[answerText] = "checked";
            var yesno = "<span class='yesno-radio required'><input class='yesno-radio-button' type='radio' name='" + radioId + "' value='Yes' " + radioChecked["Yes"] + ">Yes <input class='yesno-radio-button' type='radio' name='" + radioId + "' value='No' " + radioChecked["No"] + ">No</span>";
            var textarea = "<span class='yesno-comment'> <textarea class='yesno-textarea ui-widget-content'>" + commentText + "</textarea></span>";
            return $yesNoQuestionRow.append($(question)).append($("<span class='yesno-answer'/>").append($(yesno)).append($(textarea)));
            //return $yesNoQuestionRow.append($(yesno)).append($(question)).append($(textarea));
        }
```

Comment: Does it work when you try it?

Comment: This belongs on [codereview.stackexchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I have not yet, before I try it I just wanted to get a second opinion.

Comment: How do you determine the value of `index`; may be that the right place/time to do the value assignment. Or you would have to use: `yesNoQuestions[index].question_text = $(item).find("input, select").val();`

Comment: var index = $(item).data("index"); is determined like this.

Comment: Unless you have put a data attribute on each question like "data-index='5'" then var index = $(item).data("index"); is going to return null;

Comment: Would I need to put a data attribute on the select options as well. The input box already has a data attribute

Comment: $(item).data('index') will pull the value of the attribute "data-index" from '$(item)'  if it has the attribute. In the code you've posted your "each" statement is on the ""#questionList li". so "$(item)" is a list item element. if you want index to have a value then you have to put a 'data-index' on each list item that contains a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to get the answers submitted to all the questions, in an array something like this should work:

```
var questions = $('input:text', 'select', 'input:radio:checked', 'input:checkbox:checked');
var yesNoQuestions = $.map(questions, function(item){
    return $(item).val();
});
```

Comment: Hi Greg, Thanks for your input I have updated the code so that you'll be able to see the inner workings.

Comment: You original question was about jquery. The webservice code is irrelevent to the javascript. What I really need to see in order to help is the HTML that is being output to the browser.

Comment: Thanks, Greg this actually helped me out.